# Has the Legacy Popup stopped working in Klaviyo?

Tags: popup, subscription, subscribe, subscriptions

I was using a customized legacy popup in Klaviyo by following the instructions at https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005249548-Add-and-Customize-a-Legacy-Popup and everything was working for me correctly yesterday early in the morning. But then suddenly things were not working properly and I have not been able to fix it yet. What is happening is that people are subscribing but they are not added to a specific list, even though it was already working. I am suspecting Klaviyo changed something or has discontinued the Legacy Popup maybe.

One thing that makes me suspect that is how if you see the documentation at https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005249548-Add-and-Customize-a-Legacy-Popup, they include this image: https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/article_attachments/115002832491/signupFormPopUp.png. You can see that for the Pop Up tab, they included code. I used to see that before but it does not appear anymore. This is what I see now:

[image]

Has Klaviyo discontinued the Legacy Popup to the point that it is not subscribing people to the lists I specify? I am carefully following the steps at https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005249548-Add-and-Customize-a-Legacy-Popup, it was working for me before and suddenly it does not work properly.

EDIT 1: I was also reading https://www.klaviyo.com/blog/new-klaviyo-popup-builder and I am starting to wonder if Klaviyo is promoting the New Klaviyo Form Builder and making changes that may affect the Legacy Popup, making it obsolete, discontinued, or not working properly. This entry in their blog is from April 11, 2018, one week ago, and I started to experience the problem yesterday. Maybe Klaviyo is changing something that affects the Legacy Popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PM for Klaviyo forms here -

While we have recently released the new Klaviyo form builder, we have not made any changes to the legacy Klaviyo forms. We will continue to support legacy Klaviyo popups, and any websites using the legacy Klaviyo forms should not see any changes in the behavior of their forms.

For this reason, if you saw a change in your legacy Klaviyo popup in the last day, it's likely due to some other change on your website out of Klaviyo's control. I know you have been working with Chris in Live Chat and he found some potential issues with the php in your legacy Klaviyo form code, so I would recommend working with him and the Success team to diagnose the issue in your specific legacy Klaviyo popup.

Comment: Klaviyo had flagged my IP address because over 58 attempts to sign-up from the same IP Address within 24 hours. My code was fine, including the PHP and everything but I am glad we identified the cause. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that Klaviyo flagged my IP address. It was not my fault. I was just testing my code and implementation. This was the answer from the Klaviyo team:

> Hey Jamie,
>
> Our system flagged your IP address because over 58 attempts to sign-up
>   from the same IP Address within 24 hours, to our system this looks
>   like usual signs of bots or malicious activity.  Usually we do not see
>   false positives with our List Bomb prevention, in the future if you
>   are testing your list, we always recommend testing on a lower scale,
>   testing like this may cause our system to prevent signing up again. If
>   you experience this again in the future, let me know.
>
> Francis